# Connect to SFTP using PHP and private key

Tags: php, sftp, libssh2

I have read article after article and just cannot find "the solution" that works for what I have.

I am trying to upload files via SFTP using php scripting. I have connected using CyberDuck successfully, but I need to do this programatically.

I have a .PPK file from the vendor that I used in CyberDuck. I have a username. I have the hostname. If I open the PPK file I see some Public Lines, Private Lines and Private-MAC.

Is there anyway I can access the server to do what I need to do using the information I have?

Here is the code I was playing with:

```
<?php if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
?>
<?php
$conn = ssh2_connect('hostname.com', 22);
echo $conn;
ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($conn,'USERNAME','/var/www/html/FILENAME.PPK');

// send a file
ssh2_scp_send($conn, '/var/www/html/FILETOSEND.TXT', 'FILETOSEND.TXT', 0644);
?>
```

I don't receive any errors but the file doesn't show up on the server. 
I can confirm that SSH2 is installed on my webhost.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) for what you want to achieve. It's way better than php's build in ssh2 functions and very easy to use

Comment: You don't seem to know that `ssh2_auth_pubkey_file` expects 4 arguments and not 3. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-auth-pubkey-file.php

Comment: @charlotte,  I did see that which is why I assume I am having issues. Can I break apart the PPK file into the missing elements?

Comment: The ppk extension indicates that the key is a PuTTY formatted private key. libssh2 only works with PKCS1 formatted private keys. phpseclib - as recommend by michael - supports both. See http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/compare.html#pubkey

Comment: Have a look at https://andy-carter.com/blog/connecting-to-sftp-with-php it explains how to do it

Answer (score 30):

The question is quite old, but as I was looking for exactly the same answer, here is what I managed to gather.

## First: Change key format from .ppk to .pem

.pkk keys are PuTTY format private key.

If you want to change that to .pem format, you need to install putty-tools with:

```
sudo apt install putty-tools
```

(On a Mac, install putty package with homebrew. For Windows, I have no clue.)

Then you can change the format of the key:

```
puttygen privatekey.ppk -O private-openssh -o privatekey.pem
```

Just in case you want to extract the public key from that private key, (you won't need for the rest of that answer, but just in case) it is quite easy:

```
openssl rsa -in privatekey.pem -pubout > publickey.pub
```

## Second: Login with sFTP

Now that you have the `privatekey.pem`, you can use [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) to connect via SFTP. First, install phpseclib with Composer:

```
composer require phpseclib/phpseclib
```

Then in PHP:

```php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
use phpseclib\Net\SFTP;

$sftp = new SFTP('sftp.server.com');

// create new RSA key
$privateKey = new RSA();

// in case that key has a password
$privateKey->setPassword('private key password');

// load the private key
$privateKey->loadKey(file_get_contents('/path/to/privatekey.pem'));

// login via sftp
if (!$sftp->login('username', $privateKey)) {
    throw new Exception('sFTP login failed');
}

// now you can list what's in here
$filesAndFolders = $sftp->nlist();

// you can change directory
$sftp->chdir('coolstuffdir');

// get a file
$sftp->get('remoteFile', 'localFile');

// create a remote new file with defined content
$sftp->put('newfile.txt', 'new file content');

// put a local file
$sftp->put('remote.txt', 'local.txt', NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
```

If you want more info, go to the [phpseclib sFTP feature list](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/intro.html).

Comment: If you're using phpseclib you don't need to convert ppk formatted keys to pem. phpseclib has built-in support for ppk formatted keys.

Comment: if you have an error on `NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE`, try `SFTP::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE`

Answer (score 4):

if i may share my findings based on the code sample answered by Stéphane Le Solliec, you guys have to check your phpseclib version. to check the phpseclib version by composer (windows), you just have to type in the command prompt `composer require phpseclib/phpseclib`, the result will show the version if installed.

If the phpseclib version is 1.0, i suggest that you modify the line `$sftp = new SFTP('sftp.server.com');` into `$sftp = new NET_SFTP('sftp.server.com');`

If the phpseclib version is 2.0, i suggest that you modify the line `$sftp->put('remote.txt', 'local.txt', NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);` into `$sftp->put('remote.txt', 'local.txt', SFTP::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE);`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flysystem sftp adaptor for php. You can use this in any framework using composer installation.
Flysystem Filesystem Abstraction for PHP (PHP library).

```
https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/v2/docs/
```

install the library using command.

```
composer require league/flysystem-sftp:^2.0
```

use below code to connect with SFTP using Filesystem.

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\PhpseclibV2\SftpConnectionProvider;
use League\Flysystem\PhpseclibV2\SftpAdapter;
use League\Flysystem\UnixVisibility\PortableVisibilityConverter;
use League\Flysystem\DirectoryAttributes;
use League\Flysystem\FileAttributes;
$private_key='sftp_keys/new_private.ppk';

$filesystem = new Filesystem(new SftpAdapter(
    new SftpConnectionProvider(
        'host', // host (required)
        'username', // username (required)
        null, // password (optional, default: null) set to null if privateKey is used
        $private_key, // private key (optional, default: null) can be used instead of password, set to null if password is set
        null, // passphrase (optional, default: null), set to null if privateKey is not used or has no passphrase
        22, // port (optional, default: 22)
        false, // use agent (optional, default: false)
        30, // timeout (optional, default: 10)
        10, // max tries (optional, default: 4)
        null, // host fingerprint (optional, default: null),
        null // connectivity checker (must be an implementation of 'League\Flysystem\PhpseclibV2\ConnectivityChecker' to check if a connection can be established (optional, omit if you don't need some special handling for setting reliable connections)
    ),
    '/', // root path (required)
    PortableVisibilityConverter::fromArray([
        'file' => [
            'public' => 0640,
            'private' => 0604,
        ],
        'dir' => [
            'public' => 0740,
            'private' => 7604,
        ],
    ])
));
$allFiles = $filesystem->listContents('Outbound')->toArray();
$response = $filesystem->write('Outbound/info.txt', 'Hello How are you',array());
if($response){
    echo "Success";
}else echo "Error";
print_r($allFiles );
?>
```

Composer.json looks like

```
{
    "name": "league/flysystem-sftp",
    "description": "Flysystem adapter for SFTP",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Frank de Jonge",
            "email": "info@frenky.net"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.0",
        "league/flysystem-sftp": "^2.1",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7.25"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "League\\Flysystem\\Sftp\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```